# How to test a service function in Angular that returns an $http request

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have a simple service that makes an $http request

```
angular.module('rootApp')
    .factory('projectService', ['$http', function ($http) {

        return {
            getProject: getProject,
            getProjects: getProjects,
        };

        function getProject(id) {
            return $http.get('/projects.json/', { 'params': { 'id': id }});
        }
    }]);
```

I'm wondering how can I test this simply and cleanly? Here's what I have so far in my test.

```
describe("Root App", function () {

var mockGetProjectResponse = null,
    $httpBackend = null;

beforeEach(module('rootApp'));

beforeEach(inject(function (_$httpBackend_, projectService) {
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    $httpBackend.when('GET', '/projects.json/?id=1').response(mockGetProjectResponse);
}));

describe("should get projects successfully", inject(function (projectService) {

    it("should return project", function () {

        // I essentially want to do something like this (I know this isn't the right format).. but:             

        //expect(projectService.getProject(1)).toBe(mockGetProjectResponse);

    });
}));
```

I want to avoid explicitly calling $http.get(...) in my test, and rather stick to calling the service function, i.e. projectService.getProject(1). What I'm stuck on is not being able to do something like this:

```
projectService.getProject(1)
    .success(function (data) {
                expect(data).toBe(whatever);
            })
            .error(function () {

            });
```

Since there's 'no room' to call $httpBackend.flush();

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Testing promises is PITA a bit. But the thing that this one shouldn't be tested. You obviously test $http itself here, that was done by Angular framework before. Was the spec simplified for the question?

Comment: @estus, yeah it was simplified for the question, only one more function that's similar in the service other than what's shown. Yeah good point. Just testing the $http.get by itself is probably fine for this case since that's all that's happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual recipe for testing promises (including `$http`) is

```
it("should return project", function () {
    var resolve = jasmine.createSpy('resolve');
    projectService.getProject(1).then(resolve);
    expect(resolve).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockGetProjectResponse);
});
```

A good alternative is [jasmine-promise-matchers](https://github.com/bvaughn/jasmine-promise-matchers) which eliminates the need for spy boilerplate code.

[Here's a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/g3FCwJBN2RQ0ikJ8PkV8?p=preview) that demonstrates both of them.

Generally the one may want to keep the methods that make `$http` calls as thin as possible and stub them instead, so mocking `$httpBackend` may not be required at all.

In current example the spec tests literally nothing and can be omitted and left to e2e tests if the code coverage isn't an end in itself.

Comment: hmm I couldn't seem to get that to work. I ended up just assigning the function call to a variable, then flushing the httpBackend, then comparing the $$state.value.data to the expected result

Comment: I've updated the answer with working example. I don't consider $$ things prohibited, but it can (and sometimes does) change without notice and thus is unacceptable for the use in tests because it is required to be tested in the first place.