# Testing service that returns promise in Angular

Tags: angularjs, testing, typescript, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test my services and the data they return. I'm using Angular, Typescript and Karma. This is my service

```
/// <reference path="../../../typings/index.d.ts" />

class WeatherDataService {

  static $inject = ['$http', '$log', '$q'];

  constructor(private $http: ng.IHttpService,
              private $log: ng.ILogService,
              private $q: ng.IQService) {
    this.$http = $http;
    this.$log = $log;
    this.$q = $q;
  }

  get(params: string): ng.IPromise<{}> {
    var self = this;
    var deferred = this.$q.defer();

    this.$http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?' + params + '&appid=' + API_KEY)
      .then((response) => {
        deferred.resolve(response.data);
      }, (errors) => {
        self.$log.debug(errors);
        deferred.reject(errors.data);
      });

    return deferred.promise;
  }
}
```

And this is the WeatherDataService.spec.ts

```
/// <reference path="../../../typings/index.d.ts" />

describe('WeatherDataService', () => {
  let weatherDataService;

  var $http, $log, $q;

  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app'));

  beforeEach(inject(function (_$http_: ng.IHttpService, _$log_: ng.ILogService, _$q_: ng.IQService) {
    $http = _$http_;
    $log = _$log_;
    $q = _$q_;

    weatherDataService = new WeatherDataService($http, $log, $q);
  }));

  describe('testing karma', function () {
    it('Geolocation response should have a valid structure', function () {
      weatherDataService.get('lat=42.683529199999995&lon=26.309871599999997').then((response) => {
        expect(response).toBe('object');
      });
    });
  });
});
```

My main question is how to test the deferred.promise and check the structure of the received data.

**______________________EDIT______________________**

This is what I try in the spec

```
/// <reference path="../../../typings/index.d.ts" />

describe('WeatherDataServices', () => {

  let weatherDataService;

  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app'));

  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('weatherDataService'));

  var service, $httpBackend, $http,
    $scope = {valid: true, response: {}};

  beforeEach(inject(function ($injector: ng.auto.IInjectorService) {
    service = $injector.get('WeatherDataService');
    $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
    $http = $injector.get('$http');
  }));

  it('should demonstrate using when (200 status)', () => {
    $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .success(function(data: any) {
        $scope.valid = true;
        $scope.response = data;
      })
      .error(function(data: any) {
        $scope.valid = false;
      });

    expect($scope.valid).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

I get `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$http.get')`. I just want to test my service that is `weatherDataService.get(params)` and it works in my controller.

**______________________EDIT______________________**

This is the error that I'm getting with the provided answer.

```
Geolocation response should have a valid structure FAILED
forEach@bower_components/angular/angular.js:321:24
loadModules@bower_components/angular/angular.js:4601:12
createInjector@bower_components/angular/angular.js:4523:30
workFn@bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3074:60
loaded@http://localhost:9876/context.js:151:17
bower_components/angular/angular.js:4641:53
forEach@bower_components/angular/angular.js:321:24
loadModules@bower_components/angular/angular.js:4601:12
createInjector@bower_components/angular/angular.js:4523:30
workFn@bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3074:60
loaded@http://localhost:9876/context.js:151:17
bower_components/angular/angular.js:4641:53
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.006 secs / 0.014 secs)
[15:24:52] 'karma:single-run' errored after 2.26 s
[15:24:52] Error: Failed 1 tests.
at failCount (F:\var\www\compucorp\task1\gulp_tasks\karma.js:13:22)
at removeAllListeners
(F:\var\www\compucorp\task1\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:379:7)
at Server.<anonymous>
(F:\var\www\compucorp\task1\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:390:9)
at Server.g (events.js:286:16)
at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
at Server.emit (events.js:185:7)
at emitCloseNT (net.js:1548:8)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:71:11)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
[15:24:52] 'test' errored after 3.87 s
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Comment: The way to run `expect` is to trigger the digest with $rootScope.$apply() afterwards. https://github.com/bvaughn/jasmine-promise-matchers is a nice alternative. Btw, the code uses [deferred antipattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern).

Comment: I injected the rootscope and tried $rootScope.$apply(); afterwards, but it's still the same. Can you post the solution as an answer?

Comment: I've added this as an answer. I don't see where $http request is mocked. If the real spec looks the same, it won't work for this reason.

Comment: Can you add the code in your answer, because I tried and I'm getting undefined when I try to inject http?

Comment: Please, update the code in the question with your current spec, so it would be clear what 'undefined' is.

Comment: Updated it, but I don't see how is that relevant. I want to test weatherDataService.get(params)

Comment: The expected request should be mocked with `$httpBackend.when` and only then the service that uses `$http` should be tested. That's because real http requests are not allowed in unit tests. `$http` shouldn't be injected or used in tests, only `$httpBackend`. [Here's an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33589854/how-to-test-a-service-function-in-angular-that-returns-an-http-request) of what it may look like. Since it is something that you apparently didn't know before, the topic appears to be too comprehensive to address it in a single question.

Comment: Ok, but if I add $rootScope.$digest(); from your answer I get  WeatherDataService Geolocation response should have a valid structure FAILED                                                    Error: Unexpected request: GET http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=42.683529199999995&lon=26.309871599999997. How should I fix it?

Comment: That's what previous comments regarding `$httpBackend` (and `$httpBackend.when` in particular) are about.

Comment: Ok, but what you wrote in your answer with $rootScope.digest(); throws an error undefined is not an object about the service. Why is it doing so?

Comment: The thing about `undefined` is what I wondered about. That's because you didn't inject $rootScope. I've updated the answer.

Comment: No, I had the $rootScope injected before. It's not the problem. Still giving me the same problem about the service. I'm not sure why is the service working in my controller, but I can't use it in the test.

Comment: There's no $rootScope injected in your code. It's not possible to debug posted code if it differs from real one. It is not clear what 'undefined is not an object' refers to. The last snippet in your question (the one with `evaluating '$http.get'`) isn't correct and should be disregarded.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, but your answer doesn't work for me either.

Answer (score 0):

The way to run expect is to trigger the digest with `$rootScope.$apply()` or `$rootScope.$digest()` afterwards.

It is also more beneficial to just inject `weatherDataService` instead of manual instantiation with `new WeatherDataService($http, $log, $q)`. It could be a matter of taste, but the problem with manual approach is that it doesn't test service annotation. So let Angular do this job for you.

```
  let $httpBackend, $rootScope;

  beforeEach(inject(function (_$httpBackend_: ng.IHttpBackendService, _$rootScope_: ng.IRootScopeService) {
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
  });

it('Geolocation response should have a valid structure', inject(function (weatherData) {
  const params = 'lat=42.683529199999995&lon=26.309871599999997';
  const API_KEY = ...;
  const url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?' + params + '&appid=' + API_KEY;

  const responseMock = {};

  $httpBackend.whenGET(url).respond(responseMock );
  weatherData.get(params).then((response) => {
    expect(response).toBe(responseMock);
  });

  // does $rootScope.$digest() internally
  $httpBackend.flush();
  $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
}));
```

[`jasmine-promise-matchers`](https://github.com/bvaughn/jasmine-promise-matchers) provide a nice alternative to assertions wrapped in promises (they essentially do a thing similar to the code above).

Comment: Now I'm getting
WeatherDataService testing karma Geolocation response should have a valid structure FAILED                                                                                                                            Error: Unexpected request: GET http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=42.683529199999995&lon=26.309871599999997

Comment: See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend on how $http should be tested. As for the promises, it is as simple as that, $rootScope.$digest() should be triggered after each and every promise chain.

Comment: Can you update your answer with the whole code that you think will test WeatherDataService and the promise returned.

Comment: It should look like that. I can't guarantee that the code will work for you because your case is complex and may differ from the code that was shown.

Comment: If the question reveals additional problems that weren't obvious at the time of writing, it is a good practice to create new questions that nail each of the problems instead of adding follow-up questions to the same question. This way the questions can get quick and quality answers.

Comment: Ok, so first I had to add the typedef so that the inject looks like function(weatherData: WeatherDataService) and add beforeEach(angular.mock.module('weatherDataService')); after the first line or I would get unknow provider. Right now I'm getting another error. I will update my question.

Comment: As I've already told in comments, PhantomJS shouldn't be used because it swallows errors. This is the case. You have 'FAILED' message but you don't have exact error message that tells why it was failed.

Comment: The project is scaffolded using yeoman, so I need to check how to change that.